# Simple linked list Vs STL::list. which one is best?

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

Simple Linked list:

```
struct Node { 
int x;
Node *next;
};
```

What are the major pros/cons of using user defined simple linked list and list container from STL? What about list performance for LL with vast number of data?

Comment: In modern C++, you might use `std::forward_list` - as lightweight as your simple list, but with a convenient STL-style interface. But `vector` is usually a better choice than either.

Comment: Majors pros of all the STL containers are: (1) they're already implemented - you don't have to spend any time writing them, (2) they're already well-used and well-tested, so probably bug-free vs. new code, (3) there is a large pool of C++ programmers who already know how to work with them.

Comment: "Simple linked list Vs STL::list", neither, linked list performance is absolutely terrible.

Comment: According to Bjarne Stroustrup `std::vector` usually outperforms linked list. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Comment: What is `STL::list`? Normally when someone says `STL`, I tend to assume they are referring to the standard library. But the fact that you've formatted it with a double colon between `STL` and `list`, makes it look like you're referring to a library that is actually named `STL`. Perhaps [this one](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/)?

Comment: One major difference is with the STL, the list functions copy the contents of a user node to / from an internal node that has next and optionally previous pointers. With your own list functions, the user code can work directly with the "internal" nodes, eliminating the copy step. For the STL, the user node could just be a pointer to some object or other node, but it's still an extra overhead.

Answer (score 8):

In most cases it is better to use standard containers because they are tested and well-known among programmers. Take into account that standard C++ library has its own single linked list named like

```
std::forward_list
```

So your question can sound as what is better to use a user-defined single linked list or `std::forward_list`. I would advice to use `std::forward_list`

Nevertheless, the standard C++ library needs a single linked list with method `push_back`. And [I already suggested that the C++ Committee should add such a container to the C++ standard library](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/LmgvApmDGZA). I even gave a name for it! :)

```
std::x_forward_list
```

Comment: And they laughed it off, as I recall.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Nobody laughed except you here.

Comment: I was probably recalling one of your other proposals, threads which often descend into name-calling, which can be quite amusing. As for this one, I've added a link to your answer.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

On the surface the question might appear to be a no-brainer, with answer “`std::list` is safer, more efficient, blah blah blah”.

But those aspects are irrelevant.

`std::list` generally has no advantage over other standard library containers. Up till and including C++03 it *could* provide constant time splicing, depending on the implementation. But that possible advantage was removed in C++11 by requiring its `size()` to be constant time (you can have one or the other be constant time, but not both).

So if you want constant time splicing, or other possible advantages of linked lists, you *have* to use something other than `std::list`.

Such as, your DIY home-grown list.

---

Constant time size requirement: C++11 §23.2.1/4 table 96:

> **”** `a.size()` `size_type` `distance(a.begin(), a.end())` constant

where the columns are *expression*, *return type*, *operational semantics* and *complexity*.

Comment: `list` does have stable iterators and constant-time insertion and removal of single elements (if you know where they are). These are sometimes useful benefits.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Constant time insertion and removal at sequentially established position is not difficult to add on top of e.g. `std::vector`. Then you avoid the cache breaking behavior of `std::list`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find that I am way more productive just using STL containers than having to design a linked list every time I wish to use one. That is probably the best benefit. Time is money.

Answer (score 1):

The STL is standard, heavily documented, already exists and has been used and tested, it is generic and works with most types, performance of STL containers is usually part of the standard so you will get the performance guaranteed from the standard or better.

A homegrown list can be specifically customized to your needs and in some cases that may allow you to have a gain in performance based on any unique aspects of your data, but there are no guarantees, the performance is only as good as you make it yourself for your data. You must perform your own tests and write your own implementation.